# How to load Data Frame or csv file in spacy pipeline nlp?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, nlp, spacy

I am trying to load data frame csv into spacy pipeline. I am getting argument string error here is my code.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
nlp = spacy.load('en')

data = pd.read_csv("sometextdata.csv")
text = []
for line in data.Line:
    text.append(clean_text(line))

    text_spacy = nlp(data['Line'])
    data['Line'].apply(nlp)
    document = nlp(text)
TypeError: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected unicode, got str)
```

I tried to load in different ways i got same error.

**Platforms** : OS - Mac and python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

You should convert variable text to unicode. As you can see for now has str type. As example you can try convert like

```
document = nlp(unicode(text))
```

or like

```
document = nlp(text.decode())
```